# Spring FTP Integration : How to verify FTP session?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am using following code to create ftpSessionfactory -

```
@Bean
@Lazy(false)
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost(server);
    sf.setPort(port);
    sf.setUsername(username);
    sf.setPassword(password);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
}
```

and following method to check if FTP session is good  -

```
private boolean isFTPSessionOK() {
    try {
        SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory = ftpSessionFactory();
        boolean open = ftpSessionFactory.getSession().isOpen();
        System.out.println("Session is good ? "+ open);
        return open;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there any other way, to  verify FTP Session instead of writing a dumb method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, you don't need that method if you use `CachingSessionFactory` already.

Each time to perform `ftpSessionFactory.getSession()` the `pool` abstraction ensures to return to you a valid, open instance.

Comment: Absolutely right. Thanks for providing this functionality.  However if remote host is down OR we pass wrong remote host while create CachingSessionFactory , application does not report any error in logs and  we are not able to track if application is working fine or not. Is there any way to get notification or error in logs in case there is any problem with ftpSession? Please advise.

Comment: Well, since `CachingSessionFactory` works in a lazy-load manner, indeed there is no any hooks to track the wrong connection options on start up. So, you definitely should provide home-cooked mechanism to verify whenever you need to be sure. So, then your method is good candidate.